# How to coorect a corrupted excel file

Tags: asp.net, excel, vba

how to correct a excel file which is on opening giving message as 'Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid,verify that the file has not been corrupted and the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: Most likely the file is *not* an Excel file. A lot of web sites and programs fake it by creating HTML or CSV files with an `.xls` extension. Try opening the file with a text editor. The (very) old `xls` files are binary files. `xlsx` files are zip packages that contain XML files

Comment: When you open such a file from Excel itself, eg through the `Data` tab, Excel detects the fake extension and shows you the import dialog that allows you to specify delimiters etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the MS Excel file in safe mode. If it's opening in safe mode then delete the COM Add-ins.

If above option won't work the repair MS Office.

Good Luck!